# ERROR: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info

Tags: firebase, flutter, debugging, cloud, backend

i Found 0 Firebase projects.
✔ Enter a project id for your new Firebase project (e.g. my-cool-project) · onoja
i New Firebase project onoja created succesfully.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase projects:create onoja --json
ERROR: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

Comment: "See firebase-debug.log for more info." Did you do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i tried creating a project on firebase using flutterfire configure but it showing me Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

Answer (score 7):

try

**$ firebase login --reauth**

if it does not work try
Open terminal.

vim .zshrc

Press "i" key to activate insert mode.

add export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Press "Esc" then write :wq in terminal and press enter to exit vim.

Reopen the terminal and check "flutterfire --version"

firebase login

flutterfire configure

if the solution above does not work try to create a project on firebase console manually, and in visual studio command flutterfire configure

Answer (score 3):

This might be caused because you're using a new firebase account on Google or because you haven't set up the proper analytics on your Google firebase account.

I got rid of this by going into Google and setting up the project manually with all their various dialogues and then from thereon all other projects did not have this error in the CLI

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

if you just start using `flutterfire configure` for the first time. It means you haven't agreed any terms of use. You should go to firebase console on website first. Then start to build any project you want. You would be asked to sign some papers during this process. Once it's done, you could use the terminal without the same error.

Comment: After having first created a test or mock project, I was then able to create a project using flutterfire configure . In my case, I am following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPvVD8t02U8 (Flutter Course for Beginners – 37-hour Cross Platform App Development Tutorial) and this is roughly at the 7:53:00 mark.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of creating a Flutter project in the command line.

Simply, the Project name should be **less than 30 characters.**

Please I hope you get the correct answer.
^^

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by removing the **space from the package name** in the terminal.

Avoid spaces when you type/paste the package name in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that I had just deleted my app from firebase before, and I hadn't deleted it from the "trash" projects